# Why Hahn Banach theorem not violated in following example?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I had shown that $f(x)=e^x$ is not tempered distribution.

It is a linear functional of $C_c^{\infty}$  but not on Schwarz space.

Clearly  $C_c^{\infty}$ is subspace of S.

I do not have an idea to show rigorously above is not violating Hanh Banach theorem.

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Why do you think Hahn-Banach _is_ violated? There are many versions of Hahn-Banach; which one would you want to apply here?  In any case you will find that there is no version whose hypotheses are met.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $f$ is a linear functional on the space of compactly supported functions but it is not continuous.

To see this, consider a sequence of functions from the Schwarz space, each supported on the interval $[n,n+1]$, whose all derivatives are at most $1/n$. Then such a sequence goes to 0 in the Schwarz space but when you hit it with $f$ it no longer does so.

As $f$ is discontinuous, it does not have a contonuous extension to the closure of the space of compactly supported functions. This has very little to do with the Hahn-Banach theorem anyway.

Comment: Dear Sir This is from exercise of Rudin Functional analysis chapter 7 problem 4 and 3. It is given in the book that continuous on compactly supported function.

Comment: You need continuity in the topology of the larger space (the one to which you want to extend)!